# Quadcopter motor speed mixing

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, non-linear-systems

I'm having trouble solving the following problem. I've designed a control system for a quadcopter, my design is built upon a nonlinear model in the affine form:

$$
\dot{x}=f(x)+g(x)u
$$

The system states are the quadcopter roll, pitch, and yaw rate, and the speeds on the inertial frame:

$$
x = [\dot{\phi} \quad \dot{\theta} \quad \dot{\psi} \quad \dot{x}_e \quad \dot{y}_e \quad \dot{z}_e]^T
$$

For simplicity, the inputs of the system are the total thrust $T$ along the vertical body axis and the torque along the center of mass $\tau_\phi$, $\tau_\theta$, and $\tau_\psi$. The relation between these inputs and the angular velocity of the propellers is given by:

$$
\cases{
T=k_T(\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2+\omega_3^2+\omega_4^4)\\\\
\tau_\phi = k_\phi(\omega_4^2+\omega_2^2)\\\\
\tau_\theta = k_\theta(\omega_3^2-\omega_1^2)\\\\
\tau_\psi = k_\psi(\omega_2^2+\omega_4^2-\omega_1^2-\omega_3^2)
}
$$

Here comes the problem, my controller outputs values in terms of $[T \quad \tau_\phi \quad \tau_\theta \quad \tau_\psi]$, I want to calculate the proper angular velocity of the propellers to generate those values. My constraints are $\omega_i\in[0, W]$, with $W$ the propeller maximum speed.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: You want to find out $\omega_i$ such that plugging in the values of $\omega_i$ in the equation will produce $T,\tau_i$?

Comment: Exactly, but if I try to use the system of equations provided and solve for $\omega_i^2$, I get negative values which are nonsense.

Comment: Do you already know the values of $T, \tau_i$ ?

Comment: also, can you show the calculation, why you are getting -ve values? thank you

Comment: The values of $T$ and $\tau_i$ are computed by the control system. If I solve the system for $\omega_i^2$ I get these equations:

$\omega_1^2=-\frac{2\,d\,u_3 +b\,l\,u_4 -d\,l\,u_1 }{4\,b\,d\,l}$
$\omega_2^2=\frac{b\,l\,u_4 -2\,d\,u_2 +d\,l\,u_1 }{4\,b\,d\,l}$
$\omega_3^2=\frac{2\,d\,u_3 -b\,l\,u_4 +d\,l\,u_1 }{4\,b\,d\,l}$
$\omega_4^2=\frac{2\,d\,u_2 +b\,l\,u_4 +d\,l\,u_1 }{4\,b\,d\,l}$. $[T,\tau_i] = [u1, ui]$

Comment: there are some combinations of $u_i$ that output negative values